# How can i pass the variable from one form to other form?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a created a login page and when a person enters his username and password the access is given **now i want to pass that username into next opening form in order to make the personal dash board.**

The code is here

admin_panel.cpp

```
#include "admin_panel.h"
#include "ui_admin_panel.h"
#include<QMessageBox>
#include "login.h"

admin_panel::admin_panel(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::admin_panel)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);


}

admin_panel::~admin_panel()
{

    delete ui;
}

void admin_panel::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Login conn;
    QMessageBox msg;
    QString Name,Surname,Role,Username, Password;
    Name = ui->txt_name->text();
    Surname = ui->txt_surname->text();
    Role = ui->txt_role->text();
    Username = ui->txt_username->text();

    Password = ui->txt_password->text();


    if(!conn.connOpen())
    {
        qDebug() << "No connection to db";
        return;
    }
     conn.connOpen();


    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO Users (Name,Surname,Role,Username,Password) VALUES(:Name,:Surname, :Role, :Username, :Password)");
    qry.bindValue(":Name", Name);
    qry.bindValue(":Surname", Surname);
    qry.bindValue(":Role", Role);
    qry.bindValue(":Username", Username);
    qry.bindValue(":Password", Password);

    if(qry.exec())
    {
        if(!qry.next())
        {
            msg.setText("Saved");
            msg.exec();
            conn.connClose();

        }
        else
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),qry.lastError().text());
        }
    }

}
```

admin_panel.h file

```
#ifndef ADMIN_PANEL_H
#define ADMIN_PANEL_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class admin_panel;
}

class admin_panel : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit admin_panel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~admin_panel();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_user_linkActivated(const QString &link);


private:
    Ui::admin_panel *ui;

};

#endif // ADMIN_PANEL_H
```

login.h file

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include<QtSql/QtSql>
#include<QDebug>
#include <QDialog>
#define path "DB.sqlite"

namespace Ui {
class Login;
}

class Login : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QSqlDatabase myDB;
    void connClose()
    {
        myDB.close();
        myDB.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
    }

    bool connOpen()
    {

        myDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        myDB.setDatabaseName(path);


            if(myDB.open())
            {
                qDebug()<<("[+]Connected to Database");
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                qDebug()<<("[!] Database not found");
                return false;
            }
    }

public:
    explicit Login(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Login();


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Login *ui;
};

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

login.cpp file

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"
#include "admin_panel.h"
#include<QMessageBox>
#define path "DB.sqlite"
Login::Login(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QFileInfo checkfile(path);

   if(checkfile.isFile())
   {
       if(connOpen())
       {
           ui->label->setText("[+]Connected to Database");

       }
       else
       {
           ui->label->setText("[!] Database not found");
       }
  }
   ui->time->setText( QTime::currentTime().toString());
}


Login::~Login()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Login::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString Username,Password;
    Username = ui->txt_user->text();
    Password = ui->txt_pass->text();

    if(!myDB.isOpen())
    {
        qDebug() << "No connection to db";
        return;
    }

   //connOpen();
    QSqlQuery qry;

    qry.prepare("SELECT Username, Password, Role FROM Users WHERE Username=\'" + Username + "\' AND Password=\'" + Password + "\'");
    if(qry.exec())
    {
        if(qry.next())
        {
            ui->label->setText("[+] Valid username and password");
            QString msg = "Username = " + qry.value(0).toString() + " \n" +
                    "Role = " + qry.value(2).toString();

            QMessageBox::warning(this,"Login was successful",msg);

             connClose();
             this->hide();
             admin_panel admin;
             admin.setModal(true);
             admin.exec();          


        }
        else
        {
            ui->label->setText("[-]Wrong username or password");
        }
    }
}

void Login::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->txt_user->setText("");
    ui->txt_pass->setText("");
}
```

And here is the main.cpp

```
#include "login.h"
#include "admin_panel.h"
#include<QDialog>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Login login;
    int q = 1;
    admin_panel admin(0);
    login.show();
    login.show();->admin();



    return a.exec();
}
```

**now after successful login from login.cpp file. How can i pass the username into the admin_panel.cpp which i can later use in labels**

Comment: The usual way to copy a string in C (it may be different in C++) is with `strcpy()`. Maybe something like: `strcpy(adminpanel.username, loginpage.username);`

Comment: ..or call some method on the target form class that takes a string parameter, or add a string property to the target form class.

Comment: Please can you elaborate because i cant understand.Please can you show an example

Comment: You may be interested in the model/view paradigm, because if you have a central model for your data you don't have to copy or "pass" the data from a window to another, the model just give the data to the window who's asking for it when that window needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use signal slot mechanism of QT. Create a SIGNAL in **login** class and SLOT in **admin_panel** and put **QObject::connect(...)** in main.cpp, then emit slot with userName from **login**.